# How can I compose multiple factories with Simple Injector?

Tags: c#, factory-pattern, simple-injector

I have `SimpleInjectorBooFactory` that creates `Boo` which consumes another factory `SimpleInjectorFooFactory`to create `Foo`. A `Boo` class will have a corresponding `Foo` class.

- MyBoo will consume MyFoo
- YourBoo will consume YourBoo

How can I set up the `container` to achieve this? Some of my thoughts were (1) inject `SimpleInjectorFooFactory` to the `SimpleInjectorBooFactory` or (2) inject `SimpleInjectorFooFactory` to `Boo` or it's class hierarchy.

```
private sealed class SimpleInjectorBarFactory : IBarFactory {
    private readonly Container container; 

    public SimpleInjectorBarFactory(Container container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public Bar CreateBar() {
        return this.container.GetInstance<Bar>();
    }
}

container.RegisterSingleton<IBarFactory, SimpleInjectorBarFactory>();

public class Bar
{
    public Bar()
    {
    }

    // TODO: Create MyFoo and call method on it.
    public CallFoo()
    {
         SimpleInjectorFooFactory.CreateMyFoo().IsCalled();
    }
}

private sealed class SimpleInjectorFooFactory : IFooFactory {
    public MyFoo CreateMyFoo() {
        return this.container.GetInstance<MyFoo>();
    }
    public YourFoo CreateYourFoo() {
        return this.container.GetInstance<YourFoo>();
    }
}
```

UPDATED:

The following is the original problem that I tried to solve with multiple factories.

```
var container = new Container();

public Setup()
{
    var bars = new Dictionary<string, InstanceProducer<IBar>>
    {
        { "MyBar", Lifestyle.Transient.CreateProducer<IBar, MyBar>(container) },
        { "YourBar", Lifestyle.Transient.CreateProducer<IBar, YourBar>(container) },
    };

    container.RegisterSingleton<IBarFactory>(
        new BarFactory(container, bars));
}

private sealed class BarFactory : IBarFactory {
    private readonly Container container;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, InstanceProducer<IBar>> bars;

    public BarFactory(Container container, bars) {
        this.container = container;
        this.bars = bars;
    }

    public MyBar CreateBar(String barName) 
    {
        return this.bars[barName].GetInstance();
    }
}

public class MyBar : IBar
{
    MyFoo myfoo;

    public MyBar(MyFoo myFoo)
    {
        this.myfoo = myFoo;
    }

    public Process()
    {
         // TODO: display yourfoo.FileContents
    }
}

public class YourBar : IBar
{
    YourFoo yourfoo;

    public YourBar(YourFoo yourFoo)
    {
        this.yourfoo = yourFoo;
    }

    public Process()
    {
         // TODO: display yourfoo.FileContents
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    protected string FileContents;

    public void FetchFileContents(string fileName)
    {
        // Read into FileContents
    }
}

// Using

var barFactory = container.GetInstance<IBarFactory>();
var myBar = barFactory.CreateBar("MayBar");
// Foo.FetchFileContents has to be called before myBar.Process is called.
myBar.Process();
```

Comment: Why do you need those factories? Why not inject `MyFoo`, `YourFoo` and `Bar` directly into the consumers that require them.

Comment: I'm using the ```SimpleInjectorBarFactory ``` because the type of ```Boo``` is resolved from a string. The ```Foo``` is like a context class with states which must be injected into ```Boo``` before any ```Boo``` method consumes it. I don't know how can I dynamically create ```Foo``` before ```Boo``` is resolved and inject at the same time. In the Microsoft Unity, there was a ```InjectorFactory``` which does not exist in the Simple Injector.

Comment: Could you update your question and replace the names of `Boo` and `Foo` etc to _actual types_ your application uses. I find it _really hard_ to grasp what it is you are trying to do; actual type names often helps a lot.

Comment: The Simple Injector equivalent of Unity's `InjectorFactory` is `Register<T>(Func<T>)`, but it's unclear to me whether that would solve your problem.

Comment: I have added the problem itself as code under **UPDATE** in the original question.

Comment: I found an [old post](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/58) describing the same problem :)